# How to change UIWebview bottom toolbar color?

Tags: ios

I have created a `UIWebview` in my app. I managed to change the background color of the navigation bar with `setTintColor`. However, I am unable to do the same for the bottom bar (with back/forward/refresh buttons). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the bottom bar yourself? It probably is an UIToolbar:

```
UIToolbar *bottomToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
bottomToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: and what if it is a TTNavigator?